# Sensors in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, erratic, gazebo-simulator, pioneer-3dx, erratic-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
I'd like to add an hokuyo laser to the pioneer that I'm simulating with gazebo. But I don't know how to do it.
I've seen that with Gazebo you can simulate an erratic robot with a laser on it.
So I added:

```
 <include filename="$(find erratic_description)/urdf/erratic_hokuyo_laser.xacro" />
 <!-- BASE LASER ATTACHMENT -->
<erratic_hokuyo_laser parent="base_link">
    <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.001" rpy="0 0 0" />
</erratic_hokuyo_laser>
```

to the *pioneer3dx.xacro*.
But when I run the simulation I can't see the laser in the robot model and /scan in the topic list.
Any advice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50638/sensors-in-gazebo/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-12-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem changing the lines added this way:

```
 <include filename="$(find p2os_urdf_mod)/defs/erratic_hokuyo_laser.xacro"/>
    
<xacro:erratic_hokuyo_laser parent="base_link">
    <origin xyz="0.01 0 0.23" rpy="0 0 0" />
</xacro:erratic_hokuyo_laser>
```

and in the "*erratic_hokuyo_laser.xarco*" I added the keyword *xacro:* before the *macro* tag:

```
<xacro:macro name="erratic_hokuyo_laser" params="parent *origin">
...
</xacro:macro>
```

Now I can see the /scan topic and map its values with rviz.

---

Originally posted by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) with karma: 255 on 2012-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2